# UILabel in UITableView

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uilabel

My question is how to add a gray edge to each label on (`UITableViewCell` that contains many 3 labels)?

So that my labels for each cell will be sepraeted by the edge.

Comment: You can create a custom cell which contains 3 label or in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method add your labels as a subview

Answer (score 0):

You can have a UIView as content of UITableViewCell by adding subviews to contentView property of UITableViewCell. 
Add your labels as subviews to the cell and to have separators in between labels you can use this kind of code

```
UIView* vertLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, 1, 44)];
vertLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.contentView addSubview:vertLineView];
```

Reference:[Draw vertical separator on UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563989/draw-vertical-separator-on-uitableviewcell)

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to separate the labels from each other, you could add a UIImageView between them with a small width (like 1 or 2 points) with a dark picture. If you want them to have border, set:

```
myLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor];
myLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
```

Don't forget to include `QuarzCore`.